# Impossible to load file or assembly System.Xml.XPath - .Net 4.6.2 referencing .Net Standard 1.3

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-assembly, assembly-loading

I'm developing an application with VS2017, `C#`, `.Net Framework 4.6.2`.

I have a class library for which I installed the [Geocoding](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net)
`Core` and `Google` nuget packages. Those are `Net Standard 1.3` libraries.

This added dependencies on a couple other libraries, along with `System.Xml.XPath`.

Though, during runtime, when I try to access one of the `Geocoding.net` methods

```
var geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder("key");

var task = geocoder.GeocodeAsync(searchString);

task.Wait()
```

I get this error

```
System.AggregateException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Easymage.TEC.Entities.Application.QueryHandlers.AddressSearchQueryHandler.Handle(AddressSearchQuery query) in C:\Users\Ludovic\Source\Repos\Easymage.TEC\Easymage.TEC.Entities.Application\QueryHandlers\AddressSearchQueryHandler.cs:line 32

Inner Exception 1:
GoogleGeocodingException: There was an error processing the geocoding request. See Status or InnerException for more information.

Inner Exception 2:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Inner Exception 3:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have no idea what to do. The System.XML.XPath file is present in the output folder.

I tried adding an assembly binding redirect :

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XPath" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and this one

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.XPath" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Nothing seems to work. I always get this error.

This is the fusion log with the binding redirect :

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Ludovic/Source/Repos/Easymage.TEC/bin/Server/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Geocoding.Google, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48f410544ef36ab4.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Ludovic\Source\Repos\Easymage.TEC\bin\Server\Debug\Easymage.TEC.ServiceHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.1.0 redirected to 4.0.2.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80131040.
```

This is the fusion log without the binding redirect :

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Ludovic/Source/Repos/Easymage.TEC/bin/Server/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Geocoding.Google, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48f410544ef36ab4.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Ludovic\Source\Repos\Easymage.TEC\bin\Server\Debug\Easymage.TEC.ServiceHost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Xml.XPath, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Ludovic/Source/Repos/Easymage.TEC/bin/Server/Debug/System.Xml.XPath.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: It would be better to post English version of error messages. Will get more traction.

Comment: @Saleem Done! :)

Comment: Tested with .net framework 4.6.2 and .net core 2.0 console project. it worked fine. no error.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having similar problem with the geocoder on 4.6.2 on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Asp.Net project, install the System.Xml.Xpath nuget package to the web project. I had this issue because I had the Geocoding lib installed to my Service project (seperate project from my API controllers). I had to manually install the Xpath nuget to the web project and it solved it.